# jquery last sibling to again comes to first sibling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just want to know that in this program when we press button next sibling will appears to be red but when last element will come program will stop i just want that after last elements it again come to first

```js
    var nextDiv = $( "#start" );
    
    nextDiv.css( "background-color", "red" );
    
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
    
      nextDiv  = nextDiv.next();
    
      $( "div" ).css( "background-color", "" );
    
      nextDiv.css( "background-color", "red" );
     
    
    });
```

```css
    div{
    
     border:1px solid black;
     width:50px;
     height: 50px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Move to Next</button> 
    
    <div id="start">div1 </div>
    
    <div>div2</div>
    
    <div>div3</div>
     
    <div>div4</div>
    
    <div>div5</div>
    <div>div6</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i have another solution

```js
    var divs = $('.divs').find('div').length;
    var count = 1;

    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        count++;
        if( count > divs){
            count = 1;
            $('div').removeClass('active');
            $('#start').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('div.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

```css
    .divs div{
     border:1px solid black;
     width:50px;
     height: 50px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px;
    }
    div.active{
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <button>Move to Next</button> 
    <div id="start" class='active'>div1 </div>
    <div>div2</div>
    <div>div3</div>
    <div>div4</div>
    <div>div5</div>
    <div>div6</div>
</div>
```

it's easy to understand for beginners

Answer (score 1):

See code and use with [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```js
var i=0;
var len=$('.box').length
$("button").click(function() {
    
      if(i==len)
      i=0;
      nextDiv  = $(".box:eq("+ i+ ")");
    
      $(".box").css( "background-color", "" );
    
      nextDiv.css( "background-color", "red" );
      i++;
    
});
```

```css
    div{
    
     border:1px solid black;
     width:50px;
     height: 50px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Move to Next</button> 
    
    <div class="box" id="start">div1 </div>
    
    <div class="box">div2</div>
    
    <div class="box">div3</div>
     
    <div class="box">div4</div>
    
    <div class="box">div5</div>
    <div class="box">div6</div>
```

Comment: happy to help:)